# angular2 use routes on web host without HashLocation Strategy

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Currently, I have an issue with refreshing the page on the web host, it always displays route not found. While searching on the internet, I found a solution with a usage of Hashlocation strategy:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      useHash: true // add's #/ hash tag to URL
}),
```

The question is , how to use the same routing on web hosting, without hashed url's and make sure page's can be refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

As I am using apache on host, solution is pretty simple.
I have created an .htaccess file in my website root directory with the following content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

It will point out all other routes back to index html and angular routing will be able to handle it properly.

Note: make sure u have a  in your head tag in index.html